# Maximum number of parallel processors in clusterR function?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, raster

I am using the `clusterR()` function to predict a `randomForest` model on a huge data set. Therefore I use a cluster with 100+ cores. My code looks like this:

```
library(randomForest)
library(raster)
library(parallel)

r <- stack("...some/multilayer/raster...")

rfo <- # load a previously calculated randomForest object

beginCluster(100)

rPred <- clusterR(r, predict, args = list(model = rfo))
```

I expected that thus all 100 initialized processors were used. However, when I look at `top` in the bash, only about 20 - 30 processes are running at full speed. All others are on sleep.

When I `getCluster()` the cluster with 100 sockets is perfectly running.

Is there any limitation to the maximum number of processors in the `clusterR` function or the `parallel` backend?

Is there any possibility to determine the maximum number of processors used in `clusterR`?

Comment: I'd assume the operation can only be parallelized into 20 - 30 independent jobs. For instance, if I do something with 30 replications I can use only 30 cores.

Comment: @Roland is there any possibility to determine the number of processes used by `clusterR`?